# React + TS: How to get all children heights?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React and Typescript, using class components. My props type looks like this:

```
type Props = {
    children?: React.ReactNodeArray;
}
```

and my render function looks something like this:

```
render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm aware of using refs to get the heights of children, but I don't think that's possible in this case. How will I be able to get the heights of children passed through props? Thanks for any help you could provide!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved this problem! The key here is to not use the `props.children` to get the children, but to use the `ref.current.childNodes` instead. Here is an example:

```
constructor() {
    this.container = React.createRef();

...

getHeights() {
    const children = this.container.current.childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
        console.log((children[i] as any).clientHeight);
}

...

render() {
    return (
        <div ref={this.container}>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `(children[i] as any)` part is necessary when using Typescript so the interpreter doesn't complain that `ChildNode` doesn't have a `clientHeight` property.

Here is a jsfiddle showing an SSCCE of this in action:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtrc30kL/)